# How to delete parts of array efficiently

Tags: numpy, scipy, cython

I am writing a numpy/cython program to compute the minors of small matrices (a lot of them).

My current function looks like (computes the minor of mat wrt. to row ii, col jj):

```
cdef float minor(np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim = 2] mat,int ii,int jj): 
    rows = range(mat.shape[0])
    col = range(mat.shape[0])
    del rows[ii]
    del col[jj]

    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim = 2] rM = (mat[rows])[:,col]

    cdef float val =  (-1)**(ii+jj) * np.linalg.det(rM)

    return val
```

After a little benchmarking, the line

```
cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim = 2] rM = (mat[rows])[:,col]
```

Is rather time consuming. Is there a better way to remove one row and one column from an two dimensional array?

Yours,

cp3028

Comment: You're likely not to get much speed-up from cython since you are relying heavily on C-API calls and you haven't typed `rows` or `col`. If you know the size of `mat` from the start, you may be able to hard code the determinant and building `rM`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're copying the memory from `(mat[rows])[:,col]`, allocation and copying is a slow process.  Is it not possible to simply make the function call `np.linalg.deg` on the chunks of `mat` in place, instead of copying it and calculating the determinant on the copy?